# Adding 10k users to 20 AD Groups 500 each using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to add a list of 10k users to 20 AD Groups 500 in each group using powershell.

If the users are only 9k, adding 500 users in each group will make 18 groups and the remaining 2 groups should be left empty.

I tried using "SKIP" command but it is repetitive.

Any Better way to Code ? Please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: you are looking at the for loop, i would guess

Comment: ForEach ($client in Get-Content $ScriptDir"\Usernames.txt" | select -first 500 | select -last 100)

{

$client.Split("\")| Out-File  $trim -Append

gc $trim | sort | get-unique > $DL


}                           These are my lines of code. Any suggestions ? It takes all the lines in the text file.

Comment: I am trying to get 401 to 500 with that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-Content $DL | select -first 400 -skip 500 | out-file $ScriptDir"\ADGroupMembers.txt"

This line skips first 500 lines and then displays 501 to 900 lines.